# Tomcat Classpath

Tags: tomcat, classpath

I have a factory method in my JSP which looks for a config file in a predefined location example \abcd\configfolder\conf.xml and i have no control over this path...i currently have the file at location C:\Myfolder\project\abcd\configfolder\conf.xml and the tomcat does not find it.. so i think i need to include C:\Myfolder\project in my tomcat class path so the factory method finds conf.xml

Can any one tell me how do i make this work..

Thanks. Kaddy

Comment: I think it would help a lot if you could provide us with the code snippet that looks for conf.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right Kanddy, put you file in a folder like 'conf'. Put the folder in the class path and in you code access the file by the path as

```
File myConfFile = new File("../conf/conf.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the absolute path (via a configuration property, for example), then you can use

```
File configFile = new File(absolutePath);
```

and this will work. Actually, using a config property passed to tomcat/your app in some way is the proper way to locate the external configuration file

Comment: let me put it other way...
when i run the following jsp in my tomcat...

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Before:cp=<%=System.getProperty("java.class.path")%>
</body>
</html>


i get this output...

Before:cp=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.24\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\lib\tools.jar

How can i make  C:\Myfolder\project appear here...?How do i set this  folder to my tomcat6 class path..

Kaddy

Answer (score 0):

I added the folder using the tomcat monitor. Tomcat->configuration->java->Classpath